# Ghostscript PDF to PAM wrong color

Tags: linux, pdf, ghostscript, command-line-interface

I am using ghostscript to convert PDF to PAM. 
Some PDF files colors will be too brightly after conversation.

I have already tried all directives for gs but there is no solution :/

```
/usr/local/bin/ghostscript/9.14/gs -q -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=0 -sDEVICE=pam -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r300x300 -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -sOutputFile=output.pam -finput.pdf
```

Comment: You should add a link to a sample pdf file that can be used to reproduce the issue

Comment: You should also use current code, the current release is 9.15. The most likely explanation is that there is colour space conversion taking place. You can control this by using ICC profiles to get a 'better' conversion.